# accessing site over https causes folder structure to be shown in browser, not application

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ssl, ubuntu, https, apache2

I have a rails 3 app running with following stack:

ubuntu lucid lynx, apache2, passenger hosted on Amazon EC2

When accessed over http, the pages load and the site has no problems at all.

Then i installed a valid SSL cert on the webserver. When i try to access the same url over https, and it looks like passenger is not being activated. instead, in the browser, the folder structure of the rails application is rendered.

What configuration changes or modifications do I need to make to Apache and/or Passenger so that the https URL returns the same thing as the corresponding http url?

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName orders.xxx.com
      DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/ps-main/current/public"
      CustomLog /var/log/apache2/orders common 
      RewriteEngine On
      RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
      RewriteRule (.*) https://orders.xxx.com%{REQUEST_URI}
      NameVirtualHost *:443
      RailsEnv production 
      <Directory /var/www/html/ps-main>
         AllowOverride all            
         Options -MultiViews         
      </Directory>
   </VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        SSLEngine on
        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/orders common
        ServerAdmin webmaster@xxx.com.com
        ServerName orders.xxx.com
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/cert.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/server.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/intermediate.pem
#        SSLProtocol all
        SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/ps-main/current/public
        <Directory /var/www/html/ps-main/current/public>
                Options -MultiViews
                AllowOverride all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

This will redirect all http traffic to https. If that's not what you need, remove the redirects.